# Go to item that links to id of current item?

Tags: org-mode

I'm setting up something similar to org-depend, but more plain-text.

I have a sub item with an id:

```
* TODO my sub task
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       b988fcc3-5f73-4f4c-8b90-38c63d3ee72c
  :END:
  task notes
```

And another task that points to it via a link with id:

```
* TODO master task
 - [ ] bake cake 
 - [ ] [[id:b988fcc3-5f73-4f4c-8b90-38c63d3ee72c][my sub task]]
```

Now for the  sub task, in the title like I want to insert an elisp link that jumps to what ever links to it. Like so:

```
* TODO my sub task [[elisp:(org-occur-link-in-agenda-files)][parent]]
```

Now when I run `org-occur-link-in-agenda-files` in <kbd>M - x</kbd> , I get a list of links. But the above command inside an elisp link in the title doesn't do anything, it just prints 't' in the output line.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

**[edit]**
This works only if the parent is below the child and only in the same file.

```
[[elisp:(search-forward-regexp (concat "id:" (org-id-get-create)))]]
```

Now it would be good to be able to go to the first matching regex item somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in: [global-goto-regex](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9408/global-goto-regex)
With the code available therein, I can add this to the child task: `[[elisp:(my/goto-parent)][parent]]` and it jumps to what ever has linked to it.