# How can I make Org expand sections while searching?

Tags: org-mode, isearch

I search Org files with `C-s` or `isearch-forward`. However, when the match is hidden inside a code block in a child several levels deep, and everything is collapsed, it takes a lot of extra keystrokes to see the match. Can `isearch-forward` or Org be configured to expand sections where matches are found?

Comment: [Related](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9408/115): The OP in this question is trying to tackle the same problem: searching the invisible text in org-mode files.

Comment: Doesn't it already reveal the match by default?

Comment: @abo-abo I thought it used to but does not. I'm using latest Org from git head. Perhaps a recent change?

Comment: My version is release_8.3beta-929-g6f66c5, but this feature was working for years.

Comment: The relevant option is `search-invisible`, though it'll only work with Isearch if the text is invisible my means of an overlay (not text properties).

Comment: @politza that doesn't expand collapsed trees.

Comment: @abo-abo I'm not clear on how your system behaves. Do trees auto-expand when you search for text that is in a collapsed tree?

Comment: The default behavior is for `org-mode` to create a local variable named `outline-isearch-open-invisible-function`, which is set to `(lambda (&rest ignore) (org-show-context 'isearch))`.  When collapsing / hiding a section in `org-mode`, an overlay is placed containing that function -- i.e., `(overlay-put o 'isearch-open-invisible (or outline-isearch-open-invisible-function 'outline-isearch-open-invisible))`.  When performing an isearch, iseach looks for an overlay with property name of `isearch-open-invisible`, and then uses a `funcall` to utilize the `... org-show-context . . .` function.

Comment: @mankoff, yes, the trees do auto-expand when I search for text in a collapsed tree. I think it's the default behavior, `reveal-mode` isn't even on.

Comment: I figured it out, and I think @politza answered but I didn't understand his reply. I had `search-invisible` set to `t`, which stops section expansion. Setting it to `nil` means sections expand when searching. Of course, now I can't search in links again... :(.

Comment: another option may be explicitly showing the entry at point: `(defadvice isearch-clean-overlays (around isearch--around activate) ad-do-it (show-entry))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `C-c /`, (`org-sparse-tree`) to generate a sparse tree, expanding the tree to display the matches.